# ObjectAnimator in Android doesn't update the View's parent

Tags: animation, android-linearlayout, android-animation, objectanimator

***Objective:***

Build a SlideUp animation in a `ImageView` with fixed height that is placed in a `LinearLayout` with `wrap_content` height.

***Problem:***

The animation runs normally, but the parent `LinearLayout` doesn't resize itself while or after the animation occurs. I mean, if it is set to "wrap_content" and the "content" changes it's position (y axis to -100), it's expected that the parent accompanies the animation, "animating" it's height to 0 as well, or not?

How can I force it to continue "wraping" the content while the animation runs?

PS: No, it's not about fillAfter, I'm using ObjectAnimator, which changes the real object properties, not only the View drawn. For instance, the click event is not being triggered on the place the image used to be before the animation.

***My code:***

`ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.menu_tile_image), "y", 0, -100);`

***Layout structure:***

`LinearLayout` (match_parent, wrap_content) > `ImageView` (fill_parent, 100)

Any clue on that? Thanks!